# NSCoder Availability

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

trying to use the initwithcoder init method in my custom NSControl Class.

It works just fine and does what I need it to do. However and this leads me to asking this question on this here forum -> in the class reference of NCControl when you scroll down to initWithCoder and click on it it states **SDKs
macOS 10.10+** which leads me to believe that it would not work and do what I need it to do on versions prior to that... Unless Apple's documentation once again is wrong...

BTW - from Apple's own reference (Online as well as offline) apparently the NSCoder Class is also suffering from this **SDKs macOS 10.10+**

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscoder

The strange thing is that in the documentation describing how a NIB is loaded and which init methods it calls on various objects, it describes initWithCoder as being the designated initializer but that documentation is from before 10.10.

Thanks to anyone who can set my mind at ease ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will not work before defined version. I think you are checking versions of Swift, if you select objective-c you should see version 10.0+ which i think should work fine for your need.  If you change the language, you can put your mind to ease :)
I am assuming if you would like to support things that far back you are going to use objective-c over swift.
Check the below image for NSCoder documentation after you select objective-c on right hand side.
[image: NSCoder]

Comment: Munir, thanks for taking the time. You are right about NSCoder Class. Switching to Objective-C does reveal 10.0+. However, if you go here https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nscontrol/1428861-initwithcoder?language=objc you will find that it states 10.10+ which would indicate that that method would not work on i.e. 10.9. But according to Apple documentation initWithCode has been around since a very long time hence my confusion